# Join table record to nested JSON

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there an integration of MySQL with JSON or we can only nest using code?

**User**

```
+----+-------+------+
| id | first | dept |
+----+-------+------+
|  1 | John  | 1    |
|  2 | Jane  | 2    |
+----+-------+------+
```

**Dept**

```
+----+----------+
| id |   name   |
+----+----------+
|  1 | admin    |
|  2 | accounts |
|  3 | sales    |
+----+----------+
```

**SQL**

```
SELECT * FROM user
INNER JOIN dept ON user.dept = dept.id
```

Current output

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "first": "John",
        "dept": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "name": "admin"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "first": "Jane",
        "dept": 2,
        "id": 2,
        "name": "accounts"
    },
]
```

Expected output

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "first": "John",
        "dept": {"id": 1, "name": "admin"}
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "first": "Jane",
        "dept": {"id": 2, "name": "accounts"}
    }
]
```

My current implementation is nesting it within the code, wondering if there are optimum solutions within SQL.

Comment: What version of MySQL? If it's before 8, it's probably easier in your application code.

Comment: I've the latest one, version 8

Comment: Is there a 1:1 relationship between user and dept?

Comment: yes it's a 1:1 relationship

Comment: I need a solution to my specific problem, the linked question isn't helping me. Nick is already working to provide the solution, please open.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fgjWpHVV8YVzZQn5Shqpo7/0

Comment: thanks I appreciate, now it's clear to me with the help of my own example, how the json object works

Comment: No worries. I could reopen this and post an answer but I don't think someone who reopens should do that. So if it does get re-opened and I notice I'll post one then.

Comment: yeah I appreciate, sometimes these people don't understand that people need specific answer to wrap their heads around it with a minimalistic example, otherwise the linked solutions are like code noise to me.